# Conditional statement in logstash output doesn’t work

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Hello I've made a conditional statement in the output of logstash, but the else statement doesn't work. When I send INFO logs they get into the if statement, but when I send logs different from these, they don't get into the else statement and they are not shown in tpms-system index.

Here is my output section:

```
output{
  stdout{
    codec => dots
  }

  if [message] =~ "\D\[INFO\s\]:.*\[ELASTICSEARCH\].*" or [message] =~ "\D\[INFO\]:.*\[ELASTICSEARCH\].*" {
   elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https://localhost:9200"]
    user => logstash
    password => logstash
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate_verification => false
    document_id => "%{fingerprint}"
    index => "beat-tpms"
   }
  }else{
   elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https://localhost:9200"]
    user => logstash
    password => logstash
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate_verification => false
    document_id => "%{fingerprint}"
    index => "tpms-system"
   }
 }
}
```

The regex expression is correct because I'm using the same in filebeat.yml file to recieve only these INFO logs and is working.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error? Do you get different than expected behaviour? What have you tried so far?

Comment: There is a missing `{` after the else. Also why do you compare to `[_source][message]` instead of `message`?

Comment: @baudsp Thanks for that {. I'm using ````[_source][message]```` syntax because of logstash docs https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html (Field references). "message" is nested property, so that's why I'm using it like this.  

@mihomir When I send INFO logs it doesn't trigger the if statement and I dont recive any logs. I recive no errors. I've tried several if statements, but still doesnt go into the if statement

Comment: @baudsp @mihomir I've used only ````[message]```` and it works but now the else statement doesnt. When I send logs different from these in if statement, they are not shown in tpms-system index

Comment: Do you have any sample logs that you could add to your question so that we can try to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason logstash doesn't send docs to tpms-system index. It turns out that it was a permission issue.